# Display number of XML elements in a textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, parsing, uitextfield

I have an XML file somewhere on the web with a couple of profiles inside it and I want the number of profiles to be displayed in a textfield.

I have a textfield called: numberOfProfiles.. so what should I do in viewDidLoad?

numberOfProfiles.Text = ???

The XML file is being parsed like this:

```
NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
NSXMLParser *parser;
ViewController *currentProfile;
bool isStatus;

ViewController *xmlParser;

-(id)loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    profile = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
    return self;
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstname"])
    {
        currentProfile = [ViewController alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"lastname"])
    {
        currentProfile = [ViewController alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"email"])
    {
        currentProfile = [ViewController alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"address"])
    {
        currentProfile = [ViewController alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstname"])
    {
        currentProfile->firstName = currentNodeContent;
        NSLog(@"%@",currentProfile->firstName);
        [profile addObject:currentProfile];

    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"lastname"])
    {
        currentProfile->lastName = currentNodeContent;
        NSLog(@"%@",currentProfile->lastName);

        [profile addObject:currentProfile];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"email"])
    {
        currentProfile->eMail = currentNodeContent;
        NSLog(@"%@",currentProfile->eMail);
        [profile addObject:currentProfile];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"address"])
    {
        currentProfile->address = currentNodeContent;
        NSLog(@"%@",currentProfile->address);
        [profile addObject:currentProfile];
    }


    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"profiles"])
    {
        [self->profile addObject:currentProfile];
        currentProfile = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
        setText:currentProfile->lastName;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
        [super viewDidLoad];
        xmlParser = [[ViewController alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://dierenpensionlindehof.nl/profiles.xml"];

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried like : numberOfProfiles.Text = @"2" ?????

Comment: you can directly take profile array count [profile count]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for just count of element you can have an instance variable like of int type numberOfProfilesCount and you can increment this in

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
     numberOfProfilesCount++;
}
```

and in

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
   numberOfProfiles.Text = [NSString stringWithFormate:@"%d", numberOfProfilesCount];
}
```

to show your element count

Comment: Thanks, but what is parserDidEndDocument? I don't have this function

Comment: its a delegate method call when parser parse every element of the XML so you can show the total count

Comment: I just put this inside a button: numberOfProfiles.Text = [NSString stringWithFormate:@"%d", numberOfProfilesCount]; and when I click this button it shows 71 and I only have 10 profiles?

Comment: Ok thanks I got it to work by putting the numberOfProfilesCount++ inside firstanmes only!

Comment: Do you know why this is not showing the profiles profilesLabel?    
    NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    
    for(ViewController *obj in profile)
    {
        // Obj will need to be casted to whatever type 'currentProfile' is
        [str appendFormat:@"\n %@", obj->firstName];
    }
    [profilesLabel setText:str];

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `profile` is a global variable, use `[profile count]` to get the number of profiles.

The try: `[numberOfProfiles setText:[[profile count] stringValue]`